# How to remove Azure Active Directory from Subscription

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I can't seem to figure out how I can delete the tenant which I have created from my Azure Subscription.  Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? It sounds like it should be easy to do, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the functionality to delete an Active Directory from a subscription is not exposed on the portal.

Comment: I am in the same boat, cannot delete a tenant as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you cannot remove AAD tenant from the Azure Portal. You also cannot rename it. The good thing is that you are not being charged for it if you are not using any special features (i.e. even if you use for just authenticating without the Two-Factor-Authentication it is still free!). And I don't recall to have seen an API via which you would be able to remove an AAD tenant.

**UPDATE**

[As of November 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/11/08/creating-and-managing-multiple-windows-azure-active-directories.aspx) you are able to rename Azure AD, Add new Azure AD, change default AD for a subscription, delete Azure AD(as long as there is not subscription attached, and no user/groups/apps objects in it).

Comment: Ya you are right,Once created you can't delete a Windows Azure Active Directory.

Comment: Update: you can rename a Windows Azure AD tenant. However you still cannot delete one

Answer (score 0):

We were eventually able to delete an Azure Active Directory instance after we deleted all mapped users (except for the administrator who was logged in) and groups.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you go through the [following list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2967860) of possible causes for not being able to delete your Azure AD:

```
You are signed in as a user for whom <Your Company Name> is the home directory 
Directory contains users besides yourself
Directory has one or more subscriptions to Microsoft Online Services. 
Directory has one or more Azure subscriptions.
Directory has one or more applications. 
Directory has one or more Multi-Factor Authentication providers. 
Directory is a "Partner" directory. 
Directory contains one or more applications that were added by a user or administrator.
```